# Prove that $x^{2} + y^{2} = -1$ has no solutions in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\omega 2^{\frac{1}{3}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm studying field theory (I'm at the very begining) and this is one of the exercices in the first chapter about field extensions.

> Let $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. Show that the equation $x^{2} + y^{2} = -1$ has no solutions in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\omega 2^{\frac{1}{3}})$.

I have no idea how to work this out. I would be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Do you know a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\omega 2^{\frac{1}{3}})$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on the hint in the comment.

We have the following isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(\omega 2^{\frac{1}{3}}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$ so solutions in one field are in bijection with solutions in another field.

But a value $x^2$ or $y^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$ is $\ge 0$, so $x^2 + y^2 \ge 0$ and can never $= -1$. By the isomorphism this also proves there are no solutions in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega 2^{\frac{1}{3}})$.

Comment: what is the isomorphism map here $\mathbb{Q}(\omega 2^{\frac{1}{3}}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$ ?

Comment: It sends $\omega 2^\frac{1}{3} \mapsto 2^\frac{1}{3}$. We can do this because these two elements are both roots of $x^3 -2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.